# The parameter is incorrect exception

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm working on a Windows Phone 7.1 project and got most of my work done and decided to add to the project the images for my tiles (62x62 and 173x173 PNGs) plus the JPG file for the splash screen (SplashScreenImage.jpg 480x800). 
Before adding these images to the project my project was running fine! After adding them and setting the tiles images to the 2 new files, my project still builds ok, but when running on the 7.1 simulator (my acer laptop doesn't have hardware assisted virtualization enabled in order to run the wp8 emulator) the app crashes when trying to load MainPage with "The parameter is incorrect" exception (in the Application_UnhandledException handler).
I've been trying to find a solution on the web for the last 1-2 days, found few mentions of this error and few possible causes, but none of my findings helped so far. The exception doesn't say anything helpful and it's getting really frustrating considering that most of the serious work is done and I'm very close to releasing the app to the marketplace.

Did anybody run into this issue before? Any ideas what could have gone wrong and how I could solve this exception? Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you in advance!
Andrei

Comment: Try deleting most of the XAML as possible from the MainPage until it runs fine. Then return elements back to the file in order to find out which XAML control is incorrectly written.

Comment: Are you sure you set the right names of the images you just added? If that is the only thing you changed, and now it suddenly stopped working, there's your problem.

Comment: @igrali I wasn't aware of any name limitation for the tile images... [link](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/wp7-application-icon-and-application-tile-icon) - did this change? I have removed the default png files and I've added the new ones (named 62.png and 173.png) and adjusted WMAppManifest.xaml accordingly.  I know that there's a limitation for the splash screen jpg which has to be named SplashScreenImage.jpg. I'll try to rename the 2 tile images ApplicationIcon.png for the 62x62 and Background.png for the 173x173 tile as soon as I get home and try to redeploy the project.

Comment: No limitations - I just wondered if you set the names properly in the manifest...

Comment: @igrali I've doubled checked that few times and the names and paths are correct, that's why it's so frustrating. I'll try tonight the approach Toni Petrina suggested

Comment: @ToniPetrina Thank you very much for your suggestion! I've managed to get a few minutes free to try your suggestion and after removing all the interface XAML from MainPage the app works again without crash! Now it's just a matter of finding the cause. Stil, considering my scenario (perfectly working project before adding the tile images and the splash screen) I really can't understand why the simple process of setting the tile images would screw up the project... I would really love to understand why...

Comment: It's always some tiny thing that you won't notice at first. But this "remove and bring back" strategy always pays off. That or create new project from scratch :P

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I wish to change the Splashscreen and other images, here is what I do:

1. Locate the file on disk using Windows Explorer.
2. Open the file using some image editor (I use Paint.NET)
3. Remove the default image and replace with your image maintaining the dimensions.
4. Save the image and return to Visual Studio.
5. Rebuild the entire project.

This works seamlessly without any errors. ;)